# how to change order of pivot columns dynamically in ag grid

Tags: angular, sorting, ag-grid-angular

I create column definition dynamically in my ag grid project.

```
ColumnDef = [
      { field: 'name', rowGroup: true},
      { field: 'fiscalPeriod',
        pivot: true,
        sortable: true,
        valueGetter: params => { return new Date(params.data.fiscalPeriod).toLocaleDateString('fa-IR', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric' });
      },
      {
        field: 'hValue',
        aggFunc: 'sum',
        width: 80,
        valueFormatter: this.utilService.percentandNegativeFormatter,
      },
      {
        field: 'value',
        aggFunc: 'sum',
        width: 150,
        valueFormatter: this.utilService.negativeFormatter,
      },]
```

this gives me a grid with columns which sorts Asc(from 2020 to 2023). Sometimes in my app, I need sort my columns desc(from 2023 to 2020).

could you please help me?